# How accurate is the viewport parameters in CSS?

Tags: css, viewport

I'm trying to make two `div`s fill up with width of the page using the viewport parameter `vw`. However, the `div`s' widths are not accurate and the overlap. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PQE5B/2)

I *could* enclose them in a container and set the widths using `%` instead, which gives the desired results. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PQE5B/3/)

My question is, why do it not work with `vw`? If it is because `viewport` is inaccurate, how inaccurate is it? And what are the causes for `viewport` to be inaccurate?

**UPDATE: When I load the first DEMO, it initially overlaps. However, when I move the slider of the window left and right several times, the overlap disappear. When I try this on my test site, the overlap is also there, but doesn't go away however I resize my window.**

Answer (score 0):

It's because your body has a margin. Set the padding/margin of the body to 0, and now it'll work.

The `vw` param in CSS is based on the whole viewport, regardless of the container it's in (`%` takes a percentage of the container). If there is not enough space in the container, you'll get behavior like this.

Comment: It works now I resized the window a few times! Thanks! But it does only works if I change the window size several times. When I load it it doesn't work straight away...And when I do that not in jsFiddle, the overlap problem still exists